# performance testing for bandwidth vs number of user

Tags: numbers, bandwidth

I have a website hosted in local server. Suppose I have 150 computers connected to that server and can access the site. 
I need to know the optimum number of users who can access the site simultaneously without any hiccups and performance issue if my bandwidth is 2Mbps. 
Basically I want to perform a  testing for the bandwidth vs optimum number of users for my website .
Anyone can suggest any tool that can help me on it or any other method...

Thanks

Comment: It depends on webpage size or file size that users download. What do you serve on your server?

Answer (score 1):

Login to any Linux/bsd desktop computer and type following command:

```
$ ab -n 1000 -c 5 http://202.54.200.1/snkpage.html
```

Where,

`-n 1000` : ab will send 1000 number of requests to server 202.54.200.1 in order to perform for the benchmarking session

`-c 5` : 5 is concurrency number i.e. ab will send 5 number of multiple requests to perform at a time to server 202.54.200.1

For example if you want to send 10 request, type following command:

```
$ ab -n 10 -c 2 http://www.somewhere.com/
```